# How to change the api authentication model instead of using default user model in laravel

Tags: laravel, api

I have two models client and user. For web login i have used user model as super admin. But i want client model to be used for the mobile login through api request.

api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function() {
    Route::resource('communities', 'communityAPIController');
    Route::resource('communities', 'communityAPIController');
    Route::resource('clients', 'ClientAPIController');
});
```

Config/auth.php

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'clients',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

         'clients' => [
             'driver' => 'eloquent',
             'model' => \App\Models\Client::class,
         ],
    ],
```

i have my Client model like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Eloquent as Model;

class Client extends Model
{

    public $table = 'clients';



    public $fillable = [
        'name',
        'phone',
        'house_no',
        'type',
        'is_approved',
        'community_id'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'name' => 'string',
        'phone' => 'string',
        'house_no' => 'string',
        'type' => 'integer',
        'is_approved' => 'boolean',
        'community_id' => 'integer'
    ];



}
```

I want to use client model instead of user model for the auth:api. Plz Help me

Comment: Please show your `App\Models\Client` logic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'clients',

        ],
    ],
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
        ],

         'clients' => [
             'driver' => 'eloquent',
             'model' => App\Models\Client::class,
             'table'=>'clients'
         ],
    ],
```

Comment: remove \ in   'clients' => [
             'driver' => 'eloquent',
             'model' => App\Models\Client::class,
             'table'=>'clients'
         ],

Comment: The auth works, but how to get the authenticated client model ??
@albus_severus

Answer (score 0):

```
        try This 

         'guards' => [
                'web' => [
                    'driver' => 'session',
                    'provider' => 'users',
                ],

                'api-clients' => [
                    'driver' => 'token',
                    'provider' => 'clients',
                ],
            ],
'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
            'table' => 'users',
        ],

        'clients' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Client::class,
            'table' => 'clients',
        ],
    ],



    also make sure to mentions drivers to be used in controller's constructor like this 
    public function __construct()
        {


        auth()->shouldUse('api-clients');


        }
```

Comment: What should i use in the api.php middelware section

Comment: if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {

        if ('api-clients' === $guard) {
            
        }
        return $next($request);
    }

Comment: where should i put this